# Unit testing Spring controllers with CSRF

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, junit, spring-security-test

I have the version 5.6.10 in the following dependencies

- `spring-security-test`
- `spring-security-core`
- `spring-security-web`

I have a controller with CSRF

```
@GetMapping(value = "/data")
public ResponseEntity<DataResponse> data(@RequestParam(required = false) Double param, CsrfToken token){
    ...
}
```

I have a JUnit test that was working before adding the `, CsrfToken token` to Repository.

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Controller.class, TestConfiguration.class})
class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
    
        mockMvc.perform(get("/.../data?param=2.0")
                    .contextPath("/CONTEXT").servletPath("/.../data")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            )
            .andExpectAll(
                status().isOk(),
                ...
            )
            .andReturn();
    }
}
```

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ReactjsControllerExceptionHandler reactjsControllerExceptionHandler() {
        return new ControllerExceptionHandler(); // is a @ControllerAdvice that extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler. I think it does not matter for this case.
    }
}
```

I am getting

> No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:502)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:201)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getResolvableConstructor(BeanUtils.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    ... 87 more
```

I already tried these options:

- `mockMvc.perform(get(...).with(csrf()))`
- Setting csfrToken as attribute:

```
.with(request -> {
    request.setAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName(), csrfToken);
    return request;
})
```

- Mocking with Mockito

```
CsrfToken csrfToken = Mockito.mock(CsrfToken.class);
Mockito.when(csrfToken.getToken()).thenReturn("myToken");
```

I am getting always the same error, what can I do?

Comment: Please add your full test to the question.

Comment: `spring` tells you: hey! I have no idea to create instance of `CsrfToken` using data coming with http request (read: `spring` does not support mapping `CsrfToken` to controller method arguments, that is actually reasonable since `CsrfToken` does not contain useful information). So, how does your Q relate to unit testing?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov because this work  in the real application, the problem is only in JUnit tests

Comment: So you add a security feeature, but disable security and thus the integration for CSRF token injection into the controller. ou are also using Spring Boot, so ditch the `@EnableWebMvc` as that will disable large parts of the auto configuration.

Comment: Why are you requiring a token in a `GET` method? Usually, those methods should be safe and thus not require such protection. Why are you injecting the `CsrfToken` instead of letting Spring Security check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite sure, that spring-security does *not* "csrf protect" GET endpoints "by default" (extend the later mentioned test with csrf "expectations" they won't hold/invalid csrf won't have effect)

- [GET and POST request vulnerable to CSRF attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/90023/6131)
- [Should I use CSRF protection for GET requests?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/115794/6131)
- *Best, ensure: GET(+ HEAD) requests DO NOT change state!*
- Documented/customizable via [`CsrfConfigurer#requireCsrfProtectionMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/CsrfConfigurer.html#requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher))

  > ... The default is to ignore GET, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS ...

Nevertheless, some "magic" makes it possible to "populate" `CsrfToken` param/attribute (also in spring-web(-security!) GET requests) ...

#### Sorry, can only partially reproduce!

- starter used: [boot:2+web+security(+devtools)](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.7.11&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.stackoverflow&artifactId=soq76011945&name=soq76011945&description=Reprod%20code%20for%20https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F76011945%2F592355&packageName=com.stackoverflow.soq76011945&dependencies=web,security,devtools)

  (For "best version match" use:

  - [parent:2.6.14](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-parent/2.6.14)
  - and `<spring-security.version>5.6.10</spring-security.version>` (property)

  )
- Sa/imple controller (in child package of main class/root package):

  ```java
  @RestController
  public class MyController {
     @GetMapping(value = "/data")
     public ResponseEntity<String> data(
       @RequestParam(required = false) Double param
     ) {
       return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello");
     }
  }
  ```
- protected by `spring-boot-starter-security` (defaults)
- (a "comparable", realistic, security-integrating, suceeding) Test:

  ```java
  import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
  import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
  import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
  import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
  import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

  @WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class)
  class MyControllerTest {

     @Autowired
     private MockMvc mockMvc;

     @Test
     void testUnatuhorized() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/data?param=2.0")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(
                        status().isUnauthorized()); // 1.
     }

     @Test
     @WithMockUser // 2.
     void testAuthorized1() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/data?param=2.0")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpectAll(
                        status().isOk(),
                        content().string("Hello"));
     }

     @Test
     void testAuthorized2() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/data?param=2.0")
                        .with(user("user")) // 3.
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpectAll(
                        status().isOk(),
                        content().string("Hello"));
     }
  }
  ```
- Modifying controller to:

  ```java
  import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
  //...
      @GetMapping(value = "/data")
      public ResponseEntity<String> data(
        @RequestParam(required = false) Double param,
        CsrfToken token /*!!*/) {
            System.err.println(token); // !
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello");
      }
  ```

  ***Doesn't break the test!***
- But `excludeAutoConfiguration = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class}` ***Does!*** (with exact same exception cause/message!;) :

  ```bash
  org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
     Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
       No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken ...
  ```

So the issue/solution must be in the missing `SecurityAutoConfiguration`:your-version/ your custom `TestConfiguration`.

... (digging source code) (`CsrfToken, LazyCsrfTokenRepository, SecurityAutoConfiguration, EnableWebSecurity, ...`)

You miss a "csrf configuration" in your (test) context, which could be eligible to populate/resolve these arguments!!

---

#### Possible fixes:

- don't `excludeAutoConfiguration = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class}` (on your `@WebMvc-/SpringBoot-Test`)
- alternatively: Add `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation to your `TestConfiguration`.

Both configure a `CsrfTokenRepository` in your (test) context, which is capable of populating/resolving these "request mapping arguments"...

- ideally you should use a "real(istic)" security configuration for "integration tests".
- ...

Comment: Do you know if is there any way to ignore it or mock the CsrfToken? I didn't want to add the security configuration in this test class, I would have to add authentication and authorization configuration and that is tested in another part of the project.

Comment: With an integration (mockmvc/full) test: no chance! You have to provide minimal/real csrf config...

Comment: minimal: `@EnableWebSecurity` on test config!?